# Clojure - n-th root algorithm - while-do loop

Tags: loops, clojure

I'm working on a Newton algorithm to count n-th root and I've encountered a problem with non-working loop. Here is the code:

```
(defn root [nth guess]
  (if (<= guess 0) "Root doesn't exists" (count_root nth guess))
)

(defn count_root nth guess [nth guess]
  (def result guess)
  (def last_result result)
  (def temp (power nth result))
  (while (> (absolute (- result last_result)) 0.01)
         (do
           (def last_result result)
           (def result ('fn [nth result guess temp] (* (/ 1.0 nth) (+ (* (- nth 1) result) (/ guess temp)))))
           (def temp (power nth result))
         )
  )
  (str "Result: " result)
)

(defn power [nth result]
  (* result (- nth 1))
)

(defn absolute [x]
  (if (>= x 0) x (- x))
)
```

When I'll comment out (while...) line, it counts one loop pass and the result is correct. But when there is (while...) line included, all code below is ignored.

I've rebuilt above code to something like this:

```
(defn power [nth result]
  (* result (- nth 1))
)

(defn absolute [x]
  (if (>= x 0) x (- x))
)

(defn is-good? [prev-result result]
  (< (absolute (- prev-result result)) 0.01)
)

(defn improve [nth result temp]
  (* (/ 1.0 nth) (+ (* (- nth 1) result) (/ result temp)))
)

(defn count-root [nth number]
  (loop [result number
         prev-result result
         temp (power nth result)]
       (let [next-result (* (/ 1.0 nth) (+ (* (- nth 1) result) (/ number temp)))])
       (if (is-good? (result next-result)) result (recur next-result)))
)

(defn root [nth number]
  (if (<= number 0) "Root doesn't exists" (count-root nth number))
)
```

But compiler throw error that next-result cannot be resolved...What's going on now?

Comment: You are making many incorrect assumptions about Clojure.  I suggest you review Brave Clojure as a start:  http://braveclojure.com

Comment: This code needs some fixes to run. You need to define your functions in the opposite order, so they're defined before they're used. You need to change `(defn count_root nth guess [nth guess] ...)` to just `(defn count_root [nth guess] ...)`. And finally, can you give some sample function calls, what they return, and what you expect?

Comment: 1) use `def` for constants. HINT: you don't need any constants for this algorithm

Comment: 2) Clojure evaluates forms in order so if you ever did need your code to look like this you would need to do `(decalre absolute)` `(declare power)` at the top of your file.  if you don't, just define the function before it is used
3) for doing looping in Clojure you would want to check out the loop recur pattern

if you refactor your code with these three things in mind your original problem will go away

Comment: @exupero: It should count root from nth and guess. For instance, when I call function like (root 2 4) it should return ~2. When I call (root 3 27) it should return ~3, etc. Now it's returning just one calculation from (def result...) line. Which is correct BTW, but it should use this result of calculation for another pass until absolute value from subtracting present and previous result will be close to zero. After that, You should get final result.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with this code. To provide you with a working example let's rewrite the `root` and `count_root` functions:

```
(defn power [nth result]
  (* result (- nth 1)))

(defn count-root [nth guess]
  (loop [result       guess
         last_result  guess
         temp         (power nth result)]
    (cond
      (> (Math/abs (- result last_result)) 0.01)
        (let [next-result (* (/ 1.0 nth) (+ (* (- nth 1) result) (/ guess temp)))]
          (recur next-result
                 result
                 (power nth next-result)))
      :else
        (str "Result: " result))))

(defn root [nth guess]
  (cond
    (<= guess 0)  "Root doesn't exists"
    :else         (count-root nth guess)))
```

Let's look at what was changed here, and try to explain it.

First, in the `count-root` function:

1. I suggest that you not use underscores in names. The most commonly followed Clojure convention is to use dashes to separate elements of function and definition names.
2. To perform a loop-with-definitions, use the `loop` construct to define where the loop begins, along with any needed definitions, and use `recur` to perform a recursive invocation of the loop with new values specified for the definitions. Note that if all the necessary definitions were given as parameters to the function `count-root` then no loop would be necessary and the recursion could go back to the start of the function.
3. I recommend that you get in the habit of using `cond` instead of `if`. The `if` function looks a *whole* lot like an `if` statement in other languages, and that gets us (well, OK, **ME** :-) into difficulties from time to time. The issue is that when you use `if` you have to remember to specify *BOTH* the "true" and "false" actions, because an `if` form can't be "short-cut". That is, if this was so in "other" languages you'd always have to write:

   IF something
     THEN true-stuff
     ELSE false-stuff
   ENDIF

or, in more Clojurist fashion

```
(if something
  true-stuff
  false-stuff)
```

In Clojure you shouldn't write

```
(if something
  true-stuff)
```

because I've found that this doesn't work correctly. If you invoke the `if` function and specify *only* the `true` argument, as you would often do in "other" programming languages, it will compile and run, but you'll get odd results, things that can't happen will happen, and generally you'll get confused until you realize you've got an `if` without a "false" half or something like that. Save yourself some trouble - use `cond` instead of `if`.
4. I suggest using `Math/abs` instead of defining your own `absolute` function.
5. Use a `let` form to define temporary values where you won't need to loop inside the form. Here I've defined `next-result` as a temporary value which I'll use in the next form.
6. Use `recur` to tail-recursively "jump" to the next-earliest recursion point. Here the next-earliest recursion point is the `loop` form. If we didn't have this `loop` form, or some other recursion point, the function definition for `count-root` would serve as a recursion point. When

Next, in the `root` function:

1. the definition of the function was incorrect in the original version. I've cleaned it up here such that the function is defined with two arguments, `nth` and `guess`.

## EDIT

In the original version of `count_root` you used the `while` function. Using `while` requires that its argument has to change, which means that it will have to deal in some manner or other with an atom; that is, it has to deal with a modifiable variable. Most of the time in Clojure, what are usually thought of as "variables" can't actually be changed. This is intentional. Clojure was intended from the outset to be used in writing multi-threaded applications, where coordinating changes to "variables" becomes a significant concern. If "variables" can't actually be changed, the need for that coordination (by means of such constructs as semaphores, critical sections, and etc) disappears. Thus, definitions of values (they're not really "variables" if they can't vary or change) are constant by default. Now, any "real" program has a need for values which change over time, and Clojure provides for such needs - but it's not the default. You must explicitly think about what needs to be modified, and you need to access those modifiable values differently.

Now, an observation for you. You may find that programming in Clojure, or in any language which makes you do things in a different manner than what you're accustomed to, will at first feel very strange, and perhaps even uncomfortably difficult. I know that's what I've gone through when learning new-to-me systems. Quite often, our thought processes get into "ruts", and anything that forces us out of those "ruts" makes us uncomfortable. But sometimes working your way through that "uncomfortable" period ends up with you having learned something valuable. If you stick with Clojure you'll learn a different way to think about software - and having multiple viewpoints from which to consider a problem is in itself a good thing.

When you're learning something new a good guide is helpful. I suggest [Clojure For The Brave And True](https://www.braveclojure.com/foreword/), which has the advantage that it's online edition is free-like-beer.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank You for that impressing explanation! I'm a beginner to Clojure and everything You wrote here is what I'm dealing with :) I like Clojure-approach to many things. It's just simplier in other languages.  Let's get back to things. I've tried Your code, but unfortunately it doesn't give a good result for me. For instance: I've tried to count a (root 2 5) and it gave me result as 5. Then I tried to count (root 2 4) and it gave me 4. (root 3 27) gave 27, etc...

Comment: I suggest you spend some time debugging it. It should prove instructive. For example, what is `power` supposed to compute?

Comment: I see, You made it by purpose, to leave some things for me to do ;) Am I right?

Comment: No - I just converted it to a more Clojure-ish style. I didn't write any bugs in intentionally, but I didn't fix any either. Looking more closely at it, I'll note that it always seems to return `guess` as its answer. That might indicate that the loop isn't being entered for some reason.